# Is there any way to delete entries of an arraylist dynamically

Tags: java, javafx

As you can see from the image below I want to select something from my table ( which changes whenever I press a button from the vertical box to the left i.e "Overview", "Orders" ... ) and delete the record from an array ( i.e. where the content comes from ).

The method I approached bellow works but it is not elegant since I have to create at most 8 if statements for each button id. Is there any way to delete the content dynamically. Is there any way for the JVM  to figure out which record belongs to which array list?

[image]

> TableController

```
@FXML
private TableView<Object> defaultTableView;

public void delete(){

if( MockServer.getServer().currentButton.equals("btnIngredients"))
    MockServer.getServer().removeIngredient(defaultTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
else if ( MockServer.------.equals("btnOrders"))
MockServer.getServer().removeOrder(defaultTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
}
```

> Controller

```
@FXML
private TableController tableController;

@FXML
public void deleteRecord(ActionEvent event){
    tableController.delete();
}
```

> MockServer

```
public class MockServer implements ServerInterface {

 public Restaurant restaurant;
 public ArrayList<Dish> dishes = new ArrayList<Dish>();
 public ArrayList<Drone> drones = new ArrayList<Drone>();
 public ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
 public ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
 public ArrayList<Staff> staff = new ArrayList<Staff>();

 public MockServer(){}

 public ArrayList<Ingredient> getIngredients() { return this.ingredients; }
 public ArrayList<Order> getOrders() { return this.orders; }
 public ArrayList<Staff> getStaff() { return this.staff; }
 ....

 static public ServerInterface getServer(){
    return server;
 }

 @Override
 public void removeIngredient(Ingredient ingredient) {
    int index = this.ingredients.indexOf(ingredient);
    this.ingredients.remove(index);
    this.notifyUpdate();
 }

}
```

Comment: when clicking on a menu you will display the list content, so why not making this list as current selected list and dropping ( deleting ) from it reference, to give you more idea please provide the menu event click

Comment: show me the click event on ingrediant button

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb wait a second

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb So basically when I click a button ( each of them has an fx:id ) I call a function which has a thread in it that returns the observable list. I use that observable list in a `TableManager` which works under factory pattern to bind my table to it.

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb I don't have much code in the function that handles the events of the buttons in the vertical box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pseudocode will need refactoring since I don't have all the code that you are using but I wish that you will get the general idea

Ok I believe that in the button click code you have to tell your mock server which list is currently used try adding this to the mock server

```
List currentList = null;

public void setCurrentList(String listName) { // you can use integer but the best is to use enum type setCurrentList(enum) this way you will get tapeSafety
     switch(listName){
        case "ingredients" : currentList = ingredients ; break;
        //other cases 
        default : throw new Exception(" list not referred error with key value"+listName);
     }
}

public void delete(Object o){
     int index = this.currentList.indexOf(o);
     this.currentList.remove(index);
}
```

now you can update you controller delete as bellow

```
public void delete(){
MockServer.getServer().delete(defaultTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());  
}
```

Why this should work?

you have to know that there is a good practice that says code to an interface, not an implementation

As you know **List** in java is an interface so when I assigned the **ingredients** object this interface will reference the same ArrayList as the object and it will take all it behaviours (how to search for an ingredient object etc...) this way when we will use the currentList on runtime after a button click we are sure that the currentList will be the same as the clicked list and pointing to the same list in the memory

Wish this simple and really resume explanation could help you

Comment: I dont know but if you are using the mock server to get the observable list than it will be better to refactor this methode that it will handle the currentList

Comment: I see, this is a nice approach! I will try it out now

Comment: In the switch am I supposed to pass the fx:id of the buttons right?

Comment: no not the fxId of the button: it will work but you will make it hard coupled so in the futur when you will need to update a view ( button or panel ...) you will have code issues

Comment: the better is to use a enumerated like 

enum ListNames { INGREDIANTS,CARS,DRINKS,OTHER ...} than use this a methode param signature

Comment: I see that would be a great idea!

Comment: One more thing are you sure that the first delete function that you wrote is supposed return boolean and not void?

Comment: yeah a void plz dont know why I did tape a boolean, May be I m too much tired

Comment: I see, no worries at all. If you gave me a this solution in that mood you're a pro :D